# Convert varchar to date Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table data like this

```
date       time       data 
25/09/07   07:49:08   A 
25/09/07   08:49:08   b 
25/09/07   08:50:08   c 
25/09/07   09:49:08   d 
26/09/07   05:21:08   e 
26/09/07   07:10:08   f 
26/09/07   09:21:08   g
```

Format date in table sql is `varchar`

I want to show table like this

```
date       time      data 
25/09/07   07:49:08   A 
25/09/07   08:49:08   b 
25/09/07   08:50:08   c 
25/09/07   09:49:08   d
```

How to query using where date between 25/09/07 00:00:00 and 25/09/07 23:59:00?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  Also, is your time field's data type also a varchar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be very simple as you can just compare strings:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE date = '25/09/07'
AND time <= '23:59:00'
```

- Since you are just checking for one date and not a range, you can just use a string `=` comparison. Any row with a different date will not be equal.
- Since time is in 24-hour format arranged `hh:MM:ss`, you can just do a lexical comparison. That is, for example, "23:58:03" is will be less than "23:59:00", as will "02:03:59".

---

To select a range of dates, the easiest way would probably be:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (CONVERT(datetime, date, 3) >= '2007-09-25'
       AND CONVERT(datetime, date, 3) < '2007-10-25')
OR    (CONVERT(datetime, date, 3) = '2007-10-25' AND time <= '23:59:00')
```

Comment: @rian Nope, not if you're just checking a single date.

Comment: if i find date between  25/09/07 00:00:00 and 25/10/07 23:59:00

Comment: @rian Then you'll have to tell us what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27295/discussion-between-lc-and-rian)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the '=' operator on the date. You might not need to include the time.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  t1.date = '25/09/07'
```

Cheers